# NAS for local IT-deployment enviroment

Tags: nas

I work at a department that produce between 100-200 units a day (laptop, desktop, servers etc) so it is not a big enviroment.
For years we have used an old HPE server for storage (old files that we need to store for different reasons, VM-backups etc), and some local services such as dns-server, ftp and few more applications but nothing advanced.
Other then that we use it as NFS server for the storage of clonezilla images (not a daily practice but for some customers this is required).

I basically know next to nothing about what kind of specs we need for a NAS, but i was given the task to find one to replace our current dying HPE server.

The minimum specs i do know of is that we need at least 8 disk slots, we will start off with 5 HDD disks (around 6TB each and minimum 7200RPM), redundant power supply and rackable chassis (it is better with more lenght than height since it will be racked in a rack-cabin. Of course hotplug is required with the disks.

We will run with raid-5 (i tried to push for raid-6 but i was overruled).

It does not have to be a monster of a NAS obviosly but it should not be so weak that it is slow to navigate.

Room for any special high speed interfaces is not a requirement but preferred.

Please help me with finding a proper NAS that can live up to the requirements and not be too costly.

I do apologize if some of the specs make no sense, as mentioned, i don't know anything about NAS in general.

I almost forgot, the power supply is 230V 10A.

Best regards,
Nuzvee

Comment: I know next to nothing about NAS, but one brand which always had a good reputation is QNAP.

Comment: Thank you Jan, just a confirmation such as this is more helpful than one might think.

Comment: It ended up with us getting a QNAP TS-877XU-RP with 5x6TB HDD disks 7200 RPM. It is working very well and lives up to everything i was hoping for and more. The GUI is incredibly easy to work with and while i wish there was a bit more "advanced option" for building more custom viewing for syslog as an example, i am constantly discovering new functions for which i have put to good use.